# after_commit block executes when parameter uses hashrocket syntax, but not when it uses colon syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-2.0, hashrocket

I have a model that's using activerecord lifecycle callbacks pretty heavily. I'm using the after_commit callback to execute sidekiq jobs that require a primary key to run, on create.

```
after_commit on: :create do
  async_process
end
```

The code inside the block is never run.

However, when I do

```
after_commit :on => :create do
  async_process
end
```

The code runs fine.

As I understand it, these two different lines should be interpreted exactly the same way. What am I missing?

I'm using ruby 2.0.0p247, Rails 3.2.17.

Comment: Are you sure you're using `on: :create` rather than `on: create`?

Comment: Looks like it should run fine.  Also, you dont need the do block. you could write it after_commit :async_process, on: :create

Comment: @muistooshort yeah, but good guess. emcanes it works with colon syntax without a do block, and with hashrocket syntax with a do block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me using same `Ruby` and `Rails` versions. Alternatively, you can try with another accepted syntax:

```
after_commit :async_process, on: :create
```

Comment: @dfried did you find that `weird` thing? Did you try alternative syntax?

Comment: It works with the alternative syntax, still doesn't work with my original one which should be identical, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've found using the aliases (rather than `:on` solved this issue for me:

```
after_create_commit { CreateS3BucketWorker.perform_async(id) }
```

All of my logic is already extracted to a sidekiq worker so creating a named function just to call the worker seemed excessive. Passing in a block let's me call the worker and keep my callback to 1 line.